# if statement with a void method

Tags: java, if-statement, types

Is it possible to make a boolean if statement, that says `if (a method that has a void data type) = true { then do the following`?

or would the method need to be a boolean as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The if-expression has to have boolean type. If it is just a call, you need to call a method that returns boolean. If you are comparing to true, generally a waste of time, you also need a boolean expression.

What are you trying to test? If you just want to find out if it completes without an exception, you can use:

```
try{
  method call
  code to execute if it does not throw an exception
} catch(ExceptionYouExpectItToThrow e) {
  code to execute if it does throw the exception
}
```

If you are trying to test something else about the method's execution, you need to specify what you are testing.

Comment: Hi, Thankyou for your responses. I am using Java. I have a series of methods that check validity of an integer, I have then combined these methods into one, so this can be called to check all validity methods. Im now trying to write an if-statement that says do this if the validity statement is true?

Comment: a simple if statement should suffice: if (is_a(val) and is_b(val) and is_c(val)) { //do something, e.g return true }

Answer (score 0):

In JS a function that doesn't return any value will be `undefined` which is a falsy value, that is it is equivalent to `false`:

```
function foo() {
    }

    if (foo()) {
    console.log("TRUE:" + foo());
    }
        else {
        console.log("FALSE:" + foo()); // outputs: FALSE: undefined
        }
```

​obviously testing the value of such a function is redundant